# The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists

Tags: powershell

My script is working, but I'm getting this error:

> The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

I'm looping to copy folders. Any idea what is going on?

```cs
    $source50 = "c:\folder\"
    $destination50 = "c:\folder1\"

    for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++) {
        $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays( + $i))
        $d2 = $d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        $v = Get-ChildItem $source50 -Recurse -Include "$d2"
 foreach ($file in $v) 
      {

               if ( Test-Path  $v.FullName)


                 {  
                    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destination50$d4)){
                    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $destination50$d4 

                    }


                     Write-Output "Copy ok " $v.FullName     
                     $bd= Copy-Item $v.FullName -Destination $destination50$d4 
                     break 


                  }

       }
```

The code is giving the error:

```
ok C:\folder\2017-12-27
ok C:\folder\2017-12-28
The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists.
At line:16 char:11
+       if ($v.Name -eq $d2) {
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

ok C:\folder\2017-12-30
The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists.
```

Comment: check $v.GetType(). I suspect that you are finding more than one file.

Comment: what is $v returning? Is it returning only one? I do not think so. Secondly, if yes , then hit a gettype with that and see it.

Comment: @EBGreen 
Yes, I'm hiring more than one folder.
I do not understand the mistake The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
$v.GetType  Name DirectoryInfo , (System.IO.FileSys...

Comment: If you are getting more than one file then $v is an ***array*** of file objects. The file objects in the array individually each have a .Name property but the array itself does not. To access the .Name property of each individual File Object that is in the array you would need to use a loop ti iterate through each File Object in the array.

Comment: Run under the debugger in ISE and you can learn and debug much about your results and how to access their members.

Comment: @EBGreen Slight correction: *access* to the `Name` property would only be a problem in PowerShell v2 and earlier, since PowerShell v3 introduced member enumeration for arrays. However, in this particular case that doesn't help, because `$v.Name -eq $d2` then compares an array of names to a single name, which still fails.

Answer (score 0):

the $v.Name throw exception because its an array object and not "System.IO." that has the property Name.

try using this code:

```
$source50 = "c:\folder\"
$destination50 = "c:\folder1\"

for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++)
{
    $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays( + $i))
    $d2 = $d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $v = Get-ChildItem  $source50 -Recurse -include "$d2"
    foreach($file in $v)
    {
        if ($file.Name -eq $d2)
        {
            Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $destination50 -Force
            Write-Host "ok" $file.FullName  | Out-File -FilePath  c:\folder\logggg.txt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: This is wrong. PowerShell will happily enumerate list values and gather the specified property value from them if such a member doesn't exist on the list itself. `(@{a = 1}, @{a = 2}).a` outputs `1\`n2`.

Comment: @ZzZombo, it's nice to comment on post after 4 years, while powershell added new features that wasn't exist when this post was posted.
the feature you described was introduced on newer versions on powershell. more than that if the writer of this post had this feature working he was nor supposed to get this error, the enumerator was supposed to return all 'Name' values in the array