# Powershell property 'timestamp' cannot be found on this object

Tags: powershell, oop, constructor

Using Powershell version 5, I am writing a Powershell module, `HandleReports.psm1` that has a class, `CodeReview`. Separately, I am writing a Powershell script, `HandleReports.tests.ps1` to test the module.
The issue I am facing, is the following error message:

```
The property 'timestamp' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the 
property exists and can be set.
At C:\MyFolder\HandleReports\HandleReports.psm1
:18 char:5
+     $this.timestamp = $timestamp
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

`HandleReports.psm1` has the following class definition:

```
class CodeReview {
  CodeReview ([string] $timestamp) {
    $this.timestamp = $timestamp
  }
}
```

`HandleReports.tests.ps1` has the following content:

```
Using module C:\MyFolder\HandleReports\HandleReports.psm1

$MyTimestamp = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ":", "." }

$MyCodeReview = [CodeReview]::new($MyTimestamp)
```

I have tried resolving this issue by:

- casting the timestamp to string type
- modifying the class constructor
- Instantiating the class inside the module itself

Also, comparing to:

https://learningintheopen.org/2020/05/07/powershell-error-the-property-cannot-be-found-on-this-object-verify-that-the-property-exists/

[The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979762/the-property-name-cannot-be-found-on-this-object-verify-that-the-property-exi)

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/391316-powershell-custom-object-not-settable

They seem to be the same error, but happening for slightly different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare the property first:

```powershell
class CodeReview {
  [string]$Timestamp
  CodeReview ([string]$timestamp) {
    $this.Timestamp = $timestamp
  }
}
```

Read more about class properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7#class-properties).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will accept this answer. And @T-Me , add your version, and we can have a look as well :)